# Xcode 10 Failing to download provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.1

Xcode can't download provisioning profiles, I m getting the error:

**Error Downloading Profiles**

**Xcode encountered a problem downloading profiles for team XXX with account xxxxx@xx.com**

The error detail:

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication
>   with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication
>   with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error
>   occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data
>   in the payload.}

- I tried to restart Xcode, Mac but it's not working!
- I also tried to remove my account and add it again
- I can login to my account via web
- I can download provisioning profiles from developer portal and install them

[image]

Comment: Sign in to Apple developer centre with the same user via web. Can you login? If no, update the account details on Xcode

Comment: Yeah, I can login :(

Comment: Hmm the error says Profile download was successful but there wasn't any profile data in the payload. Are you sure that the profiles are configured correctly? Can you manually download and install them? Or does the manual installation throw an error as well?

Comment: It's working manually!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug with Xcode 10, and it was observed earlier with Xcode 8 as well as stated at [Xcode Profiles Won't Download](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63621)

As a workaround, you can try the following steps,

> 1) Visit developer.apple.com in Safari
>
> 2) Click Account and sign in
>
> 3) Click on Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles
>
> 4) Navigate to the profile you're interested in and download it
>
> 5) Drag the downloaded profile onto Xcode's icon in the dock.
>
> At this point, your profile will be installed on your Mac and usable
>   within Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's how I m managing it now! Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: i think that they have change something in server side

Comment: This finally solved my issue after trying a ton of other stuff. Thank you!

Comment: how did you fix the issue? @RiddlerDev