# IOS Error Downloading provisioning profiles

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have added the apple id in Xcode accounts section and i am trying to download Manual profiles. when trying i am getting following error.

```
(
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningPortalErrorDomain Code=3 \"Communication with Apple failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication with Apple failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An unexpected error occurred. Profile download succeeded but there wasn't any profile data in the payload.}"
)
```

Previously its working fine. After upgraded to xcode 10.1 it is not working.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960477/xcode-10-failing-to-download-provisioning-profiles

Answer (score 0):

What I've read on that link is stated below:

also check this link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63621

1) Visit developer.apple.com in Safari

2) Click Account and sign in

3) Click on Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles

4) Navigate to the profile you're interested in and download it

5) Drag the downloaded profile onto Xcode's icon in the dock.

At this point, your profile will be installed on your Mac and usable within Xcode.

hope this helps!

have a good day