# Xcode a non-HTTP 200 response was received (400)

Tags: ios, xcode

I've used different Xcode versions in the past and now I started using Xcode 10.1 on a new mac mini 2018. As soon as I created a new project I get this error.
[error that I encounter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT0z8.png)

Comment: without additional logs and project settings, as well as OS configuration your question is hard to resolve. Try to dig into googling reasons

Comment: The version of mac OS i'm running is 10.14.3. Here's a link to more diagnostic log info: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TbBwkIwDJyV-2G8wBcWX99_Z0eqJVmcW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, cannot for the life of me see any relevant posts on Google regarding this. It is a truly bizarre error. I have Apple support and that is equal is less than zero support.

Comment: It seems you have lost your provisioning profiles.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960477/xcode-10-failing-to-download-provisioning-profiles

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that I have a working version of Xcode on a separate SSD on my hackintosh. I copied over the login keychain from it to my mac mini and boom problem solved. Provisioning and certificate are working again.